# audiodg.exe keeps growing with each Beep() function I call. System doesn't release memory

Tags: c++, windows, audio, memory-leaks, beep

Has anyone had the problem of the process audiodg.exe leaking memory when the Windows Beep(freq, duration) is called?  I guess it's not something you would ordinarily notice, but I find it useful in debugging and other things, and I noticed that each beep costs me about 1.5 MB in audiodg.exe, it keeps growing with each beep and never releases the memory unless I restart my computer or end the task.  I am using Windows 8.1, and it is found in the details tab in Task Manager.

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this problem too, did you find more information?

Comment: @gabssnake Hi. I've just posted an answer that gets rid of the leak for me, but it's not a great solution. Furthermore, this is specific to Sound Blaster I think. Good Luck.

Comment: Mine is currently at 52GB!? WTAF

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 10 now and this is still happening. This isn't a great fix, but it does get rid of the memory leak for me. Just go to your sound settings and go into the properties for the sound device you're using. For me it was Sound Blaster.

In one of the tabs there was an option to "Disable Sound Blaster Enhancements". Checking this box gets rid of the memory leak for me. As I said, it's not an ideal solution.

[image]